# Encrypting sensitive data in a financial form

Tags: encryption, tls, php, wordpress

I'm currently building a B2B E-Commerce site for a client using WordPress. We sell industrial machinery ranging in the upper $100k-$400k price range. My client would like to have their financing form online where customers/businesses enter bank account information, as well as social security numbers. He wants this form to be emailed to our financing group to process. Instead of emailing this form, could I keep the data on my SSL server and encrypt it some way then provide a login link for our financing group to use, enter a key, then display the sensitive information? We are trying to eliminate the need to fax or mail an application.

We have 2 servers, an in-house MS SQL 2008 server and a MySQL/nginx server WordPress is installed on.

After reading through many posts, what my client wants to do is a huge risk for users and our company. I'm not a security specialist, just looking for some feedback on what I should/could do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Honestly, this is a situation where I'd say, if you don't know how to do it, you shouldn't be building it. My advice is to contract a company that actual has experience in building these types of systems. Storing privacy sensitive data, such as social security number. Walk away.

Comment: I would agree with @LucasKauffman There is a huge risk involving sensitive data, It might be worth it to use a possible APi to make this work correctly since its a WP. But don't up the creek without a paddle

Comment: @LucasKauffman Yeah I was thinking the same. I want to eventually learn how to properly secure this kind of data but at this moment in development, it would be a nightmare trying to do this myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Lucas's comment, you really do not want to do this unless you know how to do it.

Storing account details and SSN's brings legal and regulatory requirements - including:

- strong encryption
- regular penetration testing
- audits

And so on.

There are many payment providers who will do this for you, meeting PCI DSS requirements etc